# Can I set the desktop to automatically lock the screen after a specified duration of inactivity?

Tags: raspbian, display, screen

I have installed a screensaver (slock) so that when I click on the screenlock icon in the lower right-hand corner of the desktop, the desktop locks out until I enter my password.

I would like to take this one step further and have the desktop lock out automatically after a certain amount of time (e.g., 10 minutes). I haven't been able to find how to configure this. I can use "xset s 600" so that the screen goes blank after 10 minutes, but this is different from locking out, since I don't need to enter my password to go back to the desktop.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 4):

I used `xscreensaver` for this.

1. You can install it with `sudo apt install xscreensaver`
2. Open the settings with `xscreensaver-demo`
3. Set `Blank After` to the time till the screen locks
4. Make sure that `Lock Screen After` is checked and set to zero
5. Set your screensaver. I personally like `abstractile`
6. Reboot computer